# Insertar datos en campo de tabla según el submit - PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una tabla en mysql que almacena datos de registro de asistencias del personal, la cual su estructura es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo 4 forms para cada tipo de registro de horario:

- Ingreso Labores
- Ingreso Almuerzo
- Salida Almuerzo
- Salida Labores

Cada uno obviamente tiene su propio submit que envían por POST los datos a la base de datos.

El problema que tengo es, como puedo insertar una fila primero solo en el campo **"hora_i_labor"**, y luego cuando ingrese su almuerzo, se registre en la misma fila en el campo **"hora_i_alm"**, luego en la misma fila su salida de almuerzo **"hora_s_alm"** y para finalizar el campo **"hora_s_labor"** cuando termine sus labores el usuario.

Nota: **Este proceso lo realizan los trabajadores diariamente.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo ideas de como podría hacerlo, pero me estoy bloqueando al plasmarlas.

---

Este es el interfaz, hay 4 botones que llaman a un modal con el mismo diseño, pero que realizan un submit diferente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Modal:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el código que estoy usando actualmente, funciona bien, pero quiero saber si hay alguna sugerencia o corrección por parte de ustedes, gracias.

```
<?php
require("../core/core_conexion.php");

date_default_timezone_set('America/Lima');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES', 'ES');

$fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d");
$hora_actual = date("H:i:s");
$mes_Actual = ucfirst(strftime("%B"));

//----INICIO EL PROCESO DE DATOS--------------

if (isset($_POST)) {
//----REGISTRO EL HORARIO DE INGRESO A LABORAR------------
    if (array_key_exists('i_lab', $_POST)){
        if($_POST['u_dni']!=""){

            $val_user_dni = $_POST['u_dni'];
            $consultaX="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_dni_name='$val_user_dni'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$consultaX);
            $countX=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
            $ver=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

            if($countX==1){
                            $_SESSION['i_lab']=$val_user_dni;
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_name']=$ver['user_nombres'];
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_lastname']=$ver['user_apellidos'];

                            $personal = $_SESSION['i_lab_name']." ".$_SESSION['i_lab_lastname'];
                            $onlyname = $_SESSION['i_lab_name'];

                $query_insert_inl = "INSERT INTO asistencias (asis_user_dni,asis_personal,asis_fecha,asis_hora_i_labor,asis_mes) VALUES ('$val_user_dni','$personal','$fecha_actual','$hora_actual','$mes_Actual')";
                $result_inl = mysqli_query($con,$query_insert_inl);

                header("location:../index2.php?saved=true&name=$onlyname");

            }
            else{ header("location:../index2.php?empty=true&du=$val_user_dni"); }
        }
    }
//----REGISTRO EL HORARIO DE SALIDA DE LABORAR------------
    elseif (array_key_exists('t_lab', $_POST)){
        if($_POST['u_dni']!=""){

            $val_user_dni = $_POST['u_dni'];
            $consultaX="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_dni_name='$val_user_dni'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$consultaX);
            $countX=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
            $ver=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

            if($countX==1){
                            $_SESSION['i_lab']=$val_user_dni;
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_name']=$ver['user_nombres'];
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_lastname']=$ver['user_apellidos'];

                            $personal = $_SESSION['i_lab_name']." ".$_SESSION['i_lab_lastname'];
                            $onlyname = $_SESSION['i_lab_name'];

                $query_insert_tel = "UPDATE asistencias SET asis_hora_s_labor='$hora_actual' WHERE asis_user_dni='$val_user_dni' AND asis_fecha='$fecha_actual'";
                $result_tel = mysqli_query($con,$query_insert_tel);

                header("location:../index2.php?saved=true&name=$onlyname");

            }
            else{ header("location:../index2.php?empty=true&du=$val_user_dni"); }
        }
    }
//----REGISTRO EL HORARIO DE INGRESO A ALMORZAR------------
    elseif (array_key_exists('i_alm', $_POST)){
        if($_POST['u_dni']!=""){

            $val_user_dni = $_POST['u_dni'];
            $consultaX="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_dni_name='$val_user_dni'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$consultaX);
            $countX=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
            $ver=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

            if($countX==1){
                            $_SESSION['i_lab']=$val_user_dni;
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_name']=$ver['user_nombres'];
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_lastname']=$ver['user_apellidos'];

                            $personal = $_SESSION['i_lab_name']." ".$_SESSION['i_lab_lastname'];
                            $onlyname = $_SESSION['i_lab_name'];

                $query_insert_ina = "UPDATE asistencias SET asis_hora_i_alm='$hora_actual' WHERE asis_user_dni='$val_user_dni' AND asis_fecha='$fecha_actual'";
                $result_ina = mysqli_query($con,$query_insert_ina);

                header("location:../index2.php?saved=true&name=$onlyname");

            }
            else{ header("location:../index2.php?empty=true&du=$val_user_dni"); }
        }
    }
//----REGISTRO EL HORARIO DE SALIDA DE ALMORZAR------------
    elseif (array_key_exists('t_alm', $_POST)){
        if($_POST['u_dni']!=""){

            $val_user_dni = $_POST['u_dni'];
            $consultaX="SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_dni_name='$val_user_dni'";
            $resultado=mysqli_query($con,$consultaX);
            $countX=mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
            $ver=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);

            if($countX==1){
                            $_SESSION['i_lab']=$val_user_dni;
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_name']=$ver['user_nombres'];
                            $_SESSION['i_lab_lastname']=$ver['user_apellidos'];

                            $personal = $_SESSION['i_lab_name']." ".$_SESSION['i_lab_lastname'];
                            $onlyname = $_SESSION['i_lab_name'];

                $query_insert_tea = "UPDATE asistencias SET asis_hora_s_alm='$hora_actual' WHERE asis_user_dni='$val_user_dni' AND asis_fecha='$fecha_actual'";
                $result_tea = mysqli_query($con,$query_insert_tea);

                header("location:../index2.php?saved=true&name=$onlyname");

            }
            else{ header("location:../index2.php?empty=true&du=$val_user_dni"); }
        }
    }
```

/***********************************************************************************************************/
    }
 ?>

Comment: se me ocurre que cuando llegan por primera vez es un insert, posterior por cada movimiento que hacen, salida, comida, etc, sea un update donde la fecha sea igual a la fecha del servidor y al id del usuario que desea hacer la actualización para que por ejemplo la hora de almuerzo que esta en ceros se actualice con el valor de la hora a la que esta saliendo

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. @AlfredoPaz tiene razón en su planteamiento. Tampoco das muchos detalles del contexto y en estos casos es muy importante conocerlo. Podemos imaginar un formulario **completo** donde se pide al usuario que se identifique, el sistema nada más identificarse busca si ya hay registro en la fecha de hoy, si lo hay, carga la información que ya tiene y da la posibilidad de actualizar la que falta (aquí hablamos de `UPDATE`) ; si no hay registro da la posibilidad de crearlo nuevo (aquí hablamos de `INSERT`)...

Comment: Usando la fecha y el dni puedes validar si ya existe un registro de un usuario en especifico al dia actual, si existe, solo actualizas el registro, de lo contrario creas una nueva entrada.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ya actualice la pregunta, muchas gracias

Comment: @LuiscYm me podrías dar una idea de como sería el código por favor.

Comment: @AlfredoPaz podrias plasmarlo en código para entenderlo mejor por favor, te lo agradecería.

Comment: Podrias hacer esto al primer botom el registro lo van a crear ahi haces un insert a la base de datos, luego para las demas acciones lo que puedes es hacer update a ese registro por filtras por el ID

Comment: Seria más fácil, si nos mostraras el código que tengas hasta ahora, y sobre ello orientarte mejor. Dado que desconocemos como procesas tu información.

Comment: Si quieres hacer algo profesional, la lógica a seguir es muy simple. **1**. En la fecha tienes el día de hoy por defecto; **2**. Pides DNI ... al ingresar el DNI o al cambiar la fecha lanzas un evento desde Javascript que hace una consulta a la base de datos la cual buscará si ya ese DNI tiene registro para esa fecha: ***a***. Si lo tiene llenas unos inputs con la información que hay de ese día (los que estén por llenar quedan vacíos) y muestras un botón `Actualizar`; ***b***. Si no hay registro muestras el form con todos los inputs vacíos y un botón `Insertar`...

Comment: ... En Javascript escucharás el click de esos botones, lanzando una nueva petición Ajax al servidor para que inserte o actualice según el caso. Ese es el planteamiento lógico que yo seguiría para resolver ese problema. Si sabes como funcionan las peticiones Ajax y cómo funcionan los *listeners* en Javascript, ya lo tienes. En cuanto al servidor, sería recoger los datos pasados por Ajax y hacer las consultas requeridas a la base de datos.

Comment: gracias a todos por su ayuda, he añadido el código que estoy usando actualmente para realizar la acción.